# How to multiply array by each element of second array and concatenate them?

Tags: python, numpy, kronecker-product

My matrix:

```
a = np.array([[1, 2], [3, 4]])
b = np.array([[5, 6]])
```

I want `c` as:

```
np.array([[5, 10, 6, 12], [15, 20, 18, 24]])
```

Entry wise multiplication of `a` by `b`, then concatenate them. How to do this effectively without double loops?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you are looking for is the [Kronecker product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_product). In Numpy, you can get it via [`numpy.kron()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.kron.html):

```py
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[1, 2], [3, 4]])
b = np.array([5, 6])  # May also be 2D, as in the question
c = np.kron(b, a)
print(c)              
# >>> [[ 5 10  6 12]
#      [15 20 18 24]]
```

The order of arguments in `kron()` matters here: writing `kron(a, b)` would produce the same values in `c`, but in different order, namely `[[5, 6, 10, 12], [15, 18, 20, 24]]`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use broadcasting and a transpose:

```
>>> a
array([[1, 2],
       [3, 4]])
>>> b
array([[5, 6]])
>>> (a[..., None] * b)
array([[[ 5,  6],
        [10, 12]],

       [[15, 18],
        [20, 24]]])
```

Then with the transpose:

```
>>> (a[..., None] * b).transpose((0,2,1))
array([[[ 5, 10],
        [ 6, 12]],

       [[15, 20],
        [18, 24]]])
```

Finally, a reshape:

```
>>> (a[..., None] * b).transpose((0,2,1)).reshape(2, -1)
array([[ 5, 10,  6, 12],
       [15, 20, 18, 24]])
```

Perhaps, it's cleaner with `np.swapaxes`:

```
>>> np.swapaxes((a[..., None] * b), 1, 2).reshape(2, -1)
array([[ 5, 10,  6, 12],
       [15, 20, 18, 24]])
```